# ¿For each en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, bucles, foreach

En Java puedes utilizar un bucle for each diciendo:

```
for (elemento e : array)
```

También en jQuery:

```
$.each(arr, function() {
```

En JavaScript sé que puedo hacer:

```
for (var i = 0; i > 10; i ++)
```

¿Pero hay alguna manera de hacer un for each en JavaScript puro?

Comment: En esta pregunta se contemplan varias soluciones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: asociación: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> PREGUNTA: **¿Hay alguna manera de realizar un bucle for-each en JavaScript puro?**
>
> RESPUESTA: **Varias maneras hay de hacerlo, tanto para Arrays como Objetos.**

---

### Maneras de iterar sobre Arrays y Objetos en JavaScript

---

#### Método Array#forEach

> [**Array.prototype.forEach( callback(valor, indice, array) )**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) *Método Array.forEach [Sólo Arrays]*

```js
var miArray = [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ];
miArray.forEach( function(valor, indice, array) {
    console.log("En el índice " + indice + " hay este valor: " + valor);
});
```

#### Método Object#keys combinado con Método Array#forEach

> [**Object.keys(objeto)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) *Para obtener en un array asociativo las propiedades de un Objeto.* ***Aportación de [eledgaar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/17647/2676)***

```js
var obj = {
  first: "John",
  last: "Doe"
}

// ES6
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => console.log(key, obj[key]))

// ES5
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key, obj[key])
})
```

#### Bucle for-i

> [**for ([expresion-inicial]; [condicion]; [expresion-final])sentencia**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for) *Bucle for-i [Sólo Arrays]*

```js
var miArray = [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ];
for (var i = 0; i < miArray.length; i+=1) {
  console.log("En el índice '" + i + "' hay este valor: " + miArray[i]);
}
```

#### Bucle for-in

> [**for (variable in objeto) sentencia**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in) *Arrays [No recomendado] y Objetos [Recomendado]*

```js
var miArray = [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ];
for (var indice in miArray) {
  console.log("En el índice '" + indice + "' hay este valor: " + miArray[indice]);
}
    
var miObjeto = { "marca":"audi", "edad":2 };
for (var propiedad in miObjeto) {
  if (miObjeto.hasOwnProperty(propiedad)) {
    console.log("En la propiedad '" + propiedad + "' hay este valor: " + miObjeto[propiedad]);
  }
}
```

#### Bucle for-of

> [**for (variable of objeto) sentencia**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of) *Para cualquier tipo Iterable (Arrays)*

```js
var miArray = [ 2, 4, 6, "hola", "mundo" ];
for (var valor of miArray) {
  console.log("Valor: " + valor);
}
```

---

#### Conclusión:

> Sí necesitas iterar sobre un Array utiliza el método **forEach** y si necesitas iterar sobre un objeto utiliza el método **for-in**.

Comment: "for-in" **no** es equivalente a "foreach", en la misma documentación que has puesto explican porque es mala idea utilizarlo para recorrer *arrays*.

Comment: Tienes razón, ahora mismo lo corrijo, error mío.

Comment: Como nota adicional el ciclo `for-of`puede ser utilizado para cualquier tipo de _iterable_ (arreglos, objeto arguments, generadores, etc.)

Comment: Añadido @enrique7mc, gracias.

Answer (score 12):

> **[Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach)** ( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )

```js
 
var arr = ["uno", "dos", "tres"];

arr.forEach(function(elemento) {
    console.log(elemento);
});
```

`forEach` acepta una función como *callback*. Al pasar esta función, que actúa como un iterador, la misma es llamada para cada elemento del `Array`.

<sup>*Nota: Funciona a partir de ECMAScript 5.</sup>

---

#### Callback

La función que es pasada como *callback* acepta 3 parámetros: el valor del elemento, el índice y una referencia al array que se está iterando. Los últimos 2 son opcionales (el primer ejemplo sólo pasaba el elemento). Si también quisieramos usar el índice:

```js
var arr = [];
arr[0]  = "cero";
arr[10] = "diez";
arr[20] = "veinte";

arr.forEach(function(elemento, indice) {
    console.log("pos=", indice, "valor=", elemento);
});
```

Además, cabe aclarar que `.forEach` no muta en absoluto al `array`. Si se cambia el valor de `elemento`, el `array` no se verá modificado (aunque sí podría llegar referenciarse para cambiar el valor).

---

#### Otras funciones similares

- **[`.every()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.16)** Sale del bucle en cuanto la función devuelve `false`.
- **[`.some()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.17)** Sale del bucle en cuanto la función devuelve `true`.

Answer (score 4):

Como apunte y corrigiendo el comentario de @dddenis sobre iterar un objeto, comentar que también se pueden recorrer objetos con este método.

El constructor Object dispone del método [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) que devuelve un Array de las propiedades de un objeto dado.

```
Object.keys(obj)
```

De esta manera podríamos iterar dicho Array y acceder a los valores de dichas propiedades de la siguiente manera:

```
const obj = {
  first: "John", 
  last: "Doe"
}

console.log(Object.keys(obj))  // ["first", "last"]

// ES6
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => console.log(key, obj[key]))

// ES5
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
  console.log(key, obj[key])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreach using await and async, check the next code:

```
const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
[1, 2, 3].forEach(async (num) => {
  await waitFor(50);
  console.log(num);
});
console.log('Done');
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, recuerda que el idioma oficial del sitio es Español, traduce tu pregunta  y es recomendado agregar una explicación, saludos.