# ¿Cómo saber si un elemento existe en mi arreglo de objetos javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Tengo una lista de objetos de la siguiente manera:

```
let arreglo = [{"sectorId":1},{"sectorId":2},{"sectorId":3},{"sectorId":4},{"sectorId":5},{"sectorId":6},{"sectorId":7},{"sectorId":8}];
```

Y necesito saber: ¿Cómo es que puedo saber si existe un objeto consultando solo por el `ID`?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Obtener indice de un elemento en un Array de Objetos JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/252455/obtener-indice-de-un-elemento-en-un-array-de-objetos-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar:

```
if(arreglo.findIndex( (e) => e.sectorId === 5) !== -1) {
// existe
} else {
 // no existe 
}
```

Luego utilizas una variable y reemplazas el 5 de ser necesario.

Acá dejo el enlace a la documentación:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

También podrías utilizar el método find el cual retorna el elemento encontrado o undefined:

```
if(arreglo.find( (e) => e.sectorId === 5)) {
// existe
} else {
 // no existe 
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Buena respuesta, sin embargo, un enlace a la documentación de [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) la haría mucho mejor.

Comment: `find` devuelve `undefined` si no existe el elemento, así que no deberías comparar con `-1`, para eso tendrías que usar `findIndex`

Comment: Correcto, @ArianJM. Ahí se encuentra editada

Answer (score 1):

**Usando filter**:
Con la funcionalidad de `array.filter()` [ver documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), puedes obtener los elementos que cumplan la condición del callback que le introduzcas.

```js
let arreglo = [{"sectorId":1},{"sectorId":2},{"sectorId":3},{"sectorId":4},{"sectorId":5},{"sectorId":6},{"sectorId":7},{"sectorId":8}];

let id=8;
let result=arreglo.filter(x=>x.sectorId==id);
console.log(result.length?"existe":"no existe");

id=9;
result=arreglo.filter(x=>x.sectorId==id);
console.log(result.length?"existe":"no existe");
```

**Usando regex:**
Es menos confiable porque utilizas el texto y podría haber un salto entre un elemento y otro, pero si utilizas bien el regex podrías lograr "filtros" más complejos. Por ejemplo si el sectorId fuese compartido entre varios nodos incluido padre o hijo (diferentes herarquía).

```js
let arreglo = [{"sectorId":1},{"sectorId":2},{"sectorId":3},{"sectorId":4},{"sectorId":5},{"sectorId":6},{"sectorId":7},{"sectorId":8}];
let id=5;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arreglo).match(`sectorId.{0,2}${id}}`)?"existe":"no existe");

id=9;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arreglo).match(`sectorId.{0,2}${id}}`)?"existe":"no existe")
```

Answer (score 1):

Si sólo quieres saber si existe en el array y no necesitas recuperarlo, puedes usar **some**, que comprueba si al menos un elemento del array cumple la condición. En teoría debe ser más eficiente que *filter*, porque en el momento que encuentra un elemento que cumpla la condición, ya no sigue recorriendo el array, mientras que *filter* procesará todos los elementos.
*find* tampoco recorre el array hasta el final si encuentra un elemento que cumpla antes, pero te devuelve un entero que tienes que comparar con -1 mientras que *some* te devuelve directamente un booleano (una diferencia menor, pero es cuestión de gustos)
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

```
if(arreglo.some(s => s.sectorId === 4)){}
```